# Get first child node of specific type - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to get a child dom element, which will be the first child of a specific type.

For example in both of these examples I want to get the `img` element:

```
<a id="mylink" href="#"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>
```

vs.

```
<a id="mylink" href="#"><span></span><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: None of the answers point out that your code is invalid, because of duplicate IDs.

Comment: @RobW - I *almost* made the same comment, but I *think* it was for demonstration purposes only. It's literally identical, except for the `span`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Whether it's for demonstration purposes or not, the IDs have to be unique. Replacing `class` with `class` would solve the problem. The answers would be different too: `.getElementsByClassName('mylink')[0]` (or whatever index) and `.querySelector('.mylink')`. With IDs, the top upvoted answer is incorrect, because if the first element is `<a id=mylink></a>`, then no `<img>` element is selected.

Comment: Ha - yes it is to demonstrate that i want to get the first child of the image type - and that it doesnt actually mean first child :)

Comment: @RobW - The OP doesn't intend that *both* elements will exist on the same page, but that both *forms* could. Put a `vs.` between them and that's what I believe the OP intended.

Comment: Nitpick: You want to find *element* nodes with a specific **tagName**. The *type* of a node is either *element*, *text*, *comment*, etc.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Try this

```
var firstIMG = document.getElementById('mylink').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

Comment: WARNING: getElementsByTagName gets any matching descendants, NOT ONLY direct children. If you actually want to get a child, then this approach may fail in cases like <a id="mylink" href="#"><span><img src="not_child.jpg" /></span><img src="first_direct_child.jpg" /></a>, because you will get the "not_child.jpg" descendant image.

Answer (score 56):

You can also use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
var firstImg = document.querySelector("#mylink > img:first-of-type");
```

Comment: `:first-child` has to be replaced with [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:first-of-type).

Answer (score 7):

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('mylink');
var images = anchor.getElementsByTagName('img');
var image = images.length ? images[0] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript function

```
function getFirst(con,tag)
{
    return con.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
}


//html markup
<a id="mylink" href="#"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>
<a id="mylink1" href="#"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>

//test
var con=document.getElementById('mylink');
var first=getFirst(con,'img');
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery killed my vanilla JavaScript! I used to be pretty confident with JS, but now find myself looking up almost everything when I have a project that can't use jQuery.

jQuery (so simple):

```
$('#mylink').children('img')[0];
```

Vanilla JS (from yogi's answer above -- thank you):

```
document.getElementById('mylink').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```