# how to choose the first child element from list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to choose the first child element `<a class="" href="/delivery">Доставка и оплата</a>` without using [href="/delivery"]

```
 <ul class="header-nav__list">
    <li><a class="" href="/delivery">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/reviews">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="/cook">Рецепты</a></li>
```

I already tried
ul:nth-child(1)
.header-nav__list:nth-child(1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first child node of specific type - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701118/get-first-child-node-of-specific-type-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `:first-child` selector. pay attention this relates to first immediate child, so that's why it goes with the `li`.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".header-nav__list li:first-child a");
elem.style.background = "red"
```

```html
<ul class="header-nav__list">
  <li><a class="" href="/delivery">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="/reviews">Отзывы</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="/cook">Рецепты</a></li>
</ul>
```